# How to show progress of optimizer without using a global variable?

Tags: python, scipy, dlib

Take this MWE:

```
import dlib
from scipy.optimize import rosen
def rosen_f(*x):
    result = rosen((x))
    global OPT_FOUND
    if result < OPT_FOUND:
        OPT_FOUND = result
        print("New min", (x), result)
    return result

dlib.find_min_global(rosen_f, [0]*5, [0.5]*5, 1000)
```

If I set OPT_FOUND = 2**30, this does print out all the improvements that find_min_global finds in the optimization.

How can I:

- Avoid using a global variable
- Add the improvements to a list that I can use in the main part of my code?

Comment: You can define a class that keeps the state in an attribute, and pass a method as the callback function.

Comment: @Barmar Could you show how to do that please?

Comment: Note that it just trades one global for another. Instead of a variable holding the optimal value, you have a variable holding an instance of the class.

Comment: Another option could be to use a decorator.

Comment: @jared How would you do that?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple example that uses a decorator to monitor the optimization. I couldn't get `dlib` to install, so I am just using `scipy.optimize.minimize`, but the decorator should work just the same. You can obviously customize the decorator more to suit your needs, I just threw together something simple.

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize, rosen

def minimizer_monitor(func):
    current_opt = np.inf
    def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
        result = func(*args, **kwargs)
        if result < current_opt:
            print(f"New min: {result}\t{args=}\t{kwargs=}")
        return result
    return wrapped

@minimizer_monitor
def rosen_f(x):
    return rosen(x)


x0 = np.ones(5)*0.25
res = minimize(rosen_f, x0, bounds=[(0, 0.5)])
```

Output:

```py
New min: 16.3125    args=(array([0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25]),)   kwargs={}
New min: 16.3124997975  args=(array([0.25000001, 0.25      , 0.25      , 0.25      , 0.25      ]),) kwargs={}
New min: 16.31250017250001  args=(array([0.25      , 0.25000001, 0.25      , 0.25      , 0.25      ]),) kwargs={}
...
New min: 2.6456658876277777 args=(array([5.00000000e-01, 2.63037401e-01, 7.99623919e-02, 1.62317055e-02,
       2.63535577e-04]),)   kwargs={}
New min: 2.6456658876277817 args=(array([5.00000000e-01, 2.63037401e-01, 7.99623819e-02, 1.62317155e-02,
       2.63535577e-04]),)   kwargs={}
New min: 2.6456658876278407 args=(array([5.00000000e-01, 2.63037401e-01, 7.99623819e-02, 1.62317055e-02,
       2.63545577e-04]),)   kwargs={}
```

Comment: I tried to get this to work with dlib using: https://bpa.st/4VXQ . But his doesn't work. The "New min" goes up and down in the output. I wonder if this is because I have to use *x ?